# Which polytopes are $01$-polytopes?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, reference-request, symmetry, polytopes

Are there some basic criteria by which to check whether a polytope $P\subset\Bbb R^n$ is a $01$-polytope, that is, can be rotated and scaled to have vertices in $\{0,1\}^n$, maybe even by using higher-dimensional space? I am especially interested in *necessary* conditions.

In particuar, which of the regular or uniform polytopes is a $01$-polytopes?  Here are some examples for which I know that they are:

- simplices (and also [hyper-simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersimplex)) .
- $n$-cubes (and also [demi-cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demihypercube)).
- [$n$-crosspolytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope).
- cartesian products of $01$-polytopes (e.g. certain prisms, [duo-prisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duoprism), ...).

I know that polytopes with a 5-fold rotational symmetry are not $01$-polytopes, e.g. the regular dodecahedron or 600-cell, since they do not have an embedding with purely rational vertex-coordinates. I also read that the [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) is not a $01$-polytope, but I have no argument for that. What about the [24-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell)?

Comment: I don't see how you can get the octahedron to be $01$.

Comment: @DanUznanski Take all the $01$-vectors is $\Bbb R^4$ with exactly two $1$-entries. This is the $(4,2)$-hypersimplex, which is the octahedron (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersimplex#Examples)).

Comment: Aha, I am allowed to embed in a higher space.  Okay this makes much more sense.

Comment: Doesn't the 5-cube have 5-fold symmetry rotating the coordinates, that is, the rotation given by the permutation matrix corresponding to the cyclic permutation (12345)?

Comment: @F.U.A.S. Well, you seem to be right. So I should be more precise, but I do not know how to write this down. I refer to the reflection group that generates this polytope. For the dodecahedron, etc. the Coxeter diagram of their group contains a $5$, but not so for the cubes. The reason is, that the resulting polytopes have irrational coordinates for every orientation and scale.

Comment: @F.U.A.S. I changed it to "5-fold *rotational* symmetry". I suppose that the permutation you gave does not fix only a single $2$-space, hence is not considered a rotation.

Comment: Indeed I thought "rotation" meant elements of $SO(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the 24-cell would be a 01-polytope, then its equatorial section, the cuboctahedron, would be too. And, iterating that argument, when the cuboctahedron would be a 01-polytope, then its equatorial section, the regular hexagon, would be too. Sure, the hexagon well can be inscribed into a cube by means of a single cut, but then it would intersect it mid-edge wise. Thus it isn't a 01-polytope. And therefore those other 2 neither.

--- rk

Answer (score 3):

One necessary condition is that the set of distances between vertices (in particular, edge lengths) must scale to a subset of
$$
\{ 1, \sqrt{2}, \ldots  \}
$$
since those are the distances between vertices of the unit cube.

Comment: Thank you. Just as a note: vertices in many of the very symmetric polytopes have exactly such distances. For example, the cuboctahedron and the 24-cell have distances $1,\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3, \sqrt 4$. I also read somewhere that the cuboctahedron ist not a $01$-polytope.

Answer (score 0):

I found two further criteria that helped me to eliminate a lot of candidates from my list of symmetric polytopes.

- Assuming a sufficiently symmetric polytope $P$ with barycenter in the origin, we can ask for the cosines $\cos\sphericalangle(v,w)$ of the angles between vectors $v$ and $w$ that belong to vertices of $P$ (in a sense, these are just the distances from Ethan's answer, but normalized in a sense). I also was able to derive a formula that gives these cosines in a $01$-polytopes in $\{0,1\}^n$, in which any two vertices have exactly $k$ one-entries. It is
  $$\frac{n i-k^2}{n k-k^2},$$
  where $i$ is the number of ones the two vectors have in common. So if you let $i$ run in $\{0,...,\max(2k-n,0)\}$ you can find all the cosines such a configuration allows. E.g., the list for the cuboctahedron and 24-cell coincide and are $\{-1,-1/2,0,1/2,1\}$. This list occures first time for $n=8,k=4$. Still, as Dr. Klitzing explained, they are no $01$-polytopes.
- If we look at $01$-polytopes $P$ in which all edges have the same length (e.g. uniform polytopes), then I was able to prove, that if you have to vertices $v$ and $w$ of $P$, their graph theoretical distance in the edge graph determines their Euclidean distance in the polytope and vice versa. This then gives an alternative proof that cuboctahedron and 24-cell are *not* $01$-polytopes: both have two distinct pairs of vertices at graph theoretical distance two, some belongs to the cosine $0$, and some to the cosine $-1/2$.